# HCL Volt service to another Notes Database

Tags: lotus-domino, hcl-domino-volt

I'm creating a new Domino Volt application on our server.
I want to populate a combobox with options coming from a Domino database on the same server.

DAS is used to get a json based on a view. The database containing the data has Anonymous reader access for testing purposes, but will require authentication in later releases.

When I open the DAS url in the browser, it returns the desired json.
[image]

However, when I try to setup a service using the url, I get the following error:
[image]

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: If you open a command window on the server and ping the hostname exactly as it appears in the URL, does it respond?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an authentication issue. If the service is secure then credentials need to be added to the service config.  This can be done by adding an authorization request header.